# Force onetbb to not parallelize

Tags: c++, tbb

I am writing some tests for an appliation I am developing. This application uses TBB and OpenMP for some loops which do some floating point operations.

However, for the tests I want this loops to run sequentially, to be able to compare if two executions give the same result.

I know with OpenMP you can do `set_omp_num_threads(1)`, but I have no idea how to disable parallelism in TBB. How is this done?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
tbb::global_control global_limit(tbb::global_control::max_allowed_parallelism, 1);
```

as described [here](https://spec.oneapi.io/versions/1.1-rev-1/elements/oneTBB/source/task_scheduler/scheduling_controls/global_control_cls.html) and [here](https://oneapi-src.github.io/oneTBB/main/tbb_userguide/Migration_Guide/Task_Scheduler_Init.html). Note that you need to keep the `global_limit` variable in scope as long as you want to enforce a single thread.